# Checking if an argument exists and is in an array, or set to default

Tags: javascript

I am trying to clean up some old code, and was wondering if there was a clean one line solution to deal with something like the following.

```
function dates(format) {
    var formats = ['DD/MM/YYYY','MM/DD/YYYY'];
    // is there a one liner for something like this? If format is undefined this will throw an error when evaluating formats.indexOf(format)
    format = (typeof format !== 'undefined' && formats.indexOf(format) >= 0) ? format : 'MM/DD/YYYY';

    // ...
```

format is an argument to a function, and I would like to do some prelim checks to make sure the input is given, and meets criteria of being in an array.

Comment: Where is `format` supposed to come from? Is this a function body? If so, show more code please.

Comment: Can you change the contents of `formats` array?

Comment: Your code is just fine, except that `==undefined` check is superfluous.

Comment: @Jack yes, this is an function body, and format is the only argument

Comment: @thg435 It is not, it is fool-proof in case if `format` is not defined at all.

Comment: @thg435 It's not superfluous if this is a function and the `format` parameters is optional.

Comment: @JenZhang could you explain what the function is supposed to do? Is there more code than this?

Comment: @VisioN: `x.indexOf(undefined)` works fine for me

Comment: @thg435 No, try `x.indexOf(xxxxxxxxx)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me, except that `==undefined` check is superfluous.

```
function dates(format) {
    var formats = ['DD/MM/YYYY','MM/DD/YYYY'];
    format = formats.indexOf(format) >= 0 ? format : 'MM/DD/YYYY';
}
```

Note that this will *not* throw an exception if you call `dates()` with no arguments at all.

If you've a lot of code like this, you might consider using an utility function like

```
function oneOf(item /*, args */) {
    args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1)
    return args.indexOf(item) >= 0 ? item : args[0];
}
```

and then:

```
function dates(format) {
    format = oneOf(format, 'MM/DD/YYYY', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
}
```

If you decide to use an object as Felix suggested, it's better to structure it like this:

```
var formats = {
    'DD/MM/YYYY': 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    'MM/DD/YYYY': 'MM/DD/YYYY',
};
```

This looks stupid at the first glance, but has two important advantages. First, the `in` check is as simple as

```
 format = formats[format] || 'DD/MM/YYYY'
```

and second, you can extend that to provide aliases for your values:

```
var formats = {
    'DD/MM/YYYY': 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    'MM/DD/YYYY': 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    'english': 'M/D/YYYY'
    'german':   'DD.MM.YYYY'
};

dates('german')
```

Comment: +1 Building on the other answers, the end product in this one is by far the best choice.

Comment: I was thinking about this two, but I did not want to duplicate the format for values and keys. Also note that `formats[format]` will "fail" for all built-in properties, such as `toString` or `valueOf`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a map to make the existence test a bit easier:

```
var formats = {
    'DD/MM/YYYY': true,
    'MM/DD/YYYY': true
};

// somewhere

format = formats.hasOwnProperty(format) ? format : 'MM/DD/YYYY';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the contents of `formats` array, like:

```
var formats = ["MM/DD/YYYY", "DD/MM/YYYY"];
```

Then you can always rewrite your code in the following way:

```
format = formats[Math.max(0, formats.indexOf(format))];
```

However if you don't know whether `format` variable was defined (as a variable), it is always good to add `typeof format !== "undefined"` check before first operation with it.

Answer (score 0):

Change `formats` to an object and it becomes a lot simpler:

```
function dates(format) {
    // value does not matter
    var formats = {'DD/MM/YYYY': 0, 'MM/DD/YYYY': 0 };

    format = format in formats ? format : 'MM/DD/YYYY';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6jvVA/

Note the value of the object properties don't really matter since we're just using the object as a list.

Comment: Which is basically the same as @Felix [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14539265/1249581).